# How do I concatenate a string array to a queue correctly?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections, queue, concatenation

I have a queue of strings:

```
Public Class QueueClient
    Private gaoFiles As New Queue(Of String)
```

and in a property call a function with the intention to concatenate an array of strings to the queue of strings:

```
    Public Property AddFiles As String()
        ...
        Set(asValue As String())
            AddFilesToQueue(asValue)
        End Set
    End Property
```

This is the called function, in which I attempt to perform the concatenation.

```
    Private Sub AddFilesToQueue(asFiles() As String)
        gaoFiles = CType(gaoFiles.Concat(asFiles), Queue(Of String))
    End Sub
End Class
```

This gets me an `InvalidCastException` (I have `Option Strict On`).

I understand, that

```
   gaoAudioFiles.Concat(asFiles)
```

tries an implicit conversion from a string array to a `Queue(Of String)`, which is not done due to my setting.

How do I cast this correctly?

gives me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work at all how you think.

The `Concat()` method on the `Queue(Of T)` type is inherited from `IEnumerable(OF T)`, and it's using that implementation, meaning all you get back is an `IEnumerable(Of T)`. This would be okay (though not very efficient) if you could cast `IEnumerable(Of T)` to a `Queue(Of T)`, but that cast doesn't exist. Instead, you'll have to Enqueue each item:

```
Private Sub AddFilesToQueue(asFiles() As String)
    For Each file As String in asFiles
        gaoFiles.Enqueue(file)
    Next file
End Sub
```

It's also kind of weird to use a Property in this way. When you use assignment semantics, the end user expects a variable to be entirely replaced with the a new value. Appending via assignment semantics is not normal. Better to settle for the just the method... but you can make the method more useful like this:

```
Public Sub AddFilesToQueue(asFiles As IEnumerable(Of String))
    For Each file As String in asFiles
        gaoFiles.Enqueue(file)
    Next file
End Sub
```

You can still pass an array directly to that method. You can also pass a List(Of String) or any other sequence that inherits from IEnumerable (and there are many).

Comment: Thanks for your time explaining that to me. (In fact, I had the loop before "detecting" the `Concat` method.) - Also thanks for your suggestion, I'll make this a method (and the "Getter" a function named Files or similar). Also, the hint with IEnumerable() was useful to me.